# Count the videos in a Youtube Playlist

Tags: code-golf, internet

## Challenge

Given a Youtube playlist, output the number of videos in it.

## I/O

The playlist will be given as an URL; for example, `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_3jnZNPYn7qUatgDYBS5NShkfXoehSRC` (this is a playlist a friend sent me to try to get me to listen to K-Pop because she's obsessed with it and I don't like it :P)

The link to a playlist is of the form `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=<id>`. The input is the URL, not the ID.

The output is to be a single integer indicating how many videos are in this playlist. You can either output the total number of videos or the number of non-deleted videos, whichever one is more golfy for you.

## Test Cases

```
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_3jnZNPYn7qUatgDYBS5NShkfXoehSRC -> 12
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIEbITAtGBebWGyBZQlkiMXwt30WqG9Bd -> 114 OR 1
```

Feel free to add more test cases.

Comment: Hats off for finding the sneakiest way of asking people to make you a library to count videos in a YouTube playlist.

Comment: I just resisted the urge to add a rickroll playlist. Or the "Dank Memes" playlist.

Comment: Off topic: I'd be more interested in a way list all videos a youtube channel has to offer.  The source code doesnt seem to include this naturally.

Comment: @Blauhirn That's an interesting idea. Maybe you could make a challenge about that.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes

Assumes that the **URL** is passed *without* the `https://`.

#### Code:

```
.w’®Ã-ƒ¢’¡`"<li>"¡2è#¬
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. Cannot be tried online, because of internet access.

#### Explanation:

```
.w                       # Receive implicit input and read all data from the url
  ’®Ã-ƒ¢’¡               # Split on the string "header-details"
          `              # Flatten once which leaves the last element on top of the stack
           "<li>"¡       # Split on the string "<li>"
                  2è     # Get the third element
                    #    # Split on spaces
                     ¬   # Retrieve the first element
```

This is what I get when running in the command line:

[image]

Comment: What sort of command line is that? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: @Okx It's [cmder](http://cmder.net/)

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Thanks for the reminder, I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

*Thanks to [Hyper Neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42649/hyper-neutrino) for finding a mistake, now corrected.*

```
Xi'wner">\n'XXn
```

The input is a string enclosed with single quotes. The output is the number of undeleted videos.

Here's an **example run** with the two test cases. As of June 13, 2017 the number of undeleted videos in the playlists are 12 and 1 respectively.

[image]

#### How it works

```
Xi          % Read string containing URL and get contents as a string
'wner">\n'  % Push this string
XX          % Regexp matching. Gives a cell array with the matched strings
n           % Number of elements. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Ha, clever regex!

Comment: What are you using to capture the screen?

Comment: @Matt [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for Windows

Comment: Question: What if I create a playlist called `"wner"`? Will it still work?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Good point. I have corrected it. BTW, the number of videos in the first list has changed

Comment: Nice fix. And yes, thanks for pointing that out. That would make sense; that's my friend's K-Pop playlist which she makes her friends listen to (including me >.<) and she keeps adding to it :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Well, in this case it looks like she _removed_ one track :-)

Comment: Oh? Hm, that's weird. I'll check and maybe ask her right now.

Answer (score 4):

## Scala 2.12, 138 bytes

```
print("""<li>.*?</li><li>(\d+).*?</li>""".r.findFirstMatchIn(scala.io.Source.fromURL(args(0),"utf-8").getLines.mkString("")).get.group(1))
```

Save it to `something.scala` and run by `scala something.scala {url}`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## JS (ES6), 68 bytes

```
x=>fetch(x).then(x=>x.text()).then(x=>alert(x.match(/(\d+) vi/)[1]))
```

Paste this in to your console on youtube.com to try:

```
(x=>fetch(x).then(x=>x.text()).then(x=>alert(x.match(/(\d+) vi/)[1])))(prompt("Enter the URL"))
```

Answer (score 4):

## bash + curl + gnu grep, 32 bytes

Finally giving Code Golf a go:

```
curl -s $1|grep -Po \\d+(?= vid)
```

- Use `curl -s` to download without any extra output.
- Pipe the output to grep (perl regex) which will output only the match

  - Match the first number that proceeds " vid"

This is golfed from how I would do this practically.

Comment: Nice first submission!

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 55 Bytes

```
"$(iwr "$args")"-match'(?s)(\d+) vid'>$null;$matches[1]
```

Browse to the site. Convert the object to a string which is the html source. Parse out the string that has a number preceding "vid" with regex.

Logic works with both test cases.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell 161 bytes

```
import Network.Curl.Download
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
z=do u<-getLine;(Right b)<-openURI u;putStrLn$show$length$B.findSubstrings(B.pack"<tr")b
```